# Node is deleted and cannot be used to create a relationship

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a node-link model ( which is a graph ) of an electricity grid in Neo4j, so this should fit like a glove.
The nodes and links are objects of their own, which are traversable in an abstract manner.
Link has a starting node (:Link) – [:begint_bij] –> (:Node) and an ending node (:Link) – [:eindigt_bij] –> (:Node)
Every :Node and :Link has references to one or more objects. Links and Nodes are uniquely defined by their references in this model.

The model is generated by the object-oriented GIS model and because of the generating method ( which I have no influence on ) redundant Node Link (pairs) are in the dataset.

[Node-Link Energy Grid graph model picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Rbtk.png)

In the picture we see a cloud of Nodes ( purple ) and Links ( green ) surrounding an electricity cable.

You can see the redundant pairs clearly with a pattern:
A Node-Link pair where the Node has only relationship to ( cables, gisreferences and links ) and the link has only relationships to ( cables, gisreferences and nodes )

For removing the redundant Node-Link pairs I have come up with this query:

```
"MATCH (fld:e_lv_function_cable ) where not exists(fld.done) Return fld",
"match (fld) - [:GenObject] - (fn:Node)
 match (fn) - [:begint_bij] - (l1:Link)
with [(fn) - [] - (obj1) | labels(obj1)] AS conn1, [(l1) - [] - (obj2) | labels(obj2)] AS conn2, fn, l1, fld
where all( lb1 IN  conn1 where lb1[0] in  ['e_lv_function_cable','GisReference','Link'] )
  and all( lb2 IN  conn2 where lb2[0] in  ['e_lv_function_cable','GisReference','Node'] )
with l1, fn, fld
match (l1) - [:eindigt_bij] - (n2) 
match (l2:Link) - [r] - (fn) - [:begint_bij] - (l1) 
Call apoc.do.when (
  n2 is not null and l2 is not null and r is not null,
  'Call apoc.create.relationship(l2, type(r), {}, n2) YIELD rel Detach Delete l1, fn',
  '',
  {n2: n2, l2: l2, r: r, l1: l1, fn: fn}) YIELD value
with fld
set fld.done=true
", {batchSize:100, parallel:false}) yield batches, total return batches, total
```

And it does the job.

However in a few cases I get an error ( in the debug log ):

Failed to invoke procedure `apoc.do.when`: Caused by: org.neo4j.graphdb.NotFoundException: Node[] is deleted and cannot be used to create a relationship

And sometimes:

Failed to invoke procedure `apoc.do.when`: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Kernel API returned non-existent relationship type: -1

And the set done=true is never done.

And it almost makes sense to me.

Can anyone please:

- (better) explain to me what is causing this, and
- Point me at a query that does the job 100%

Thx.

Comment: All this complexity could have been avoided if you had used the [MERGE](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/merge/) clause to avoid creating duplicates in the first place.

Comment: the redundancy already exists in the input, so thats a no go.

Comment: With MERGE, the redundancy in the input (depending on how you load it) doesn't matter - MERGE will either behave like a MATCH if the pattern already exists, or CREATE if it doesn't. It would probably be helpful to see how you're loading the data to begin with

Comment: The nodes/links are functiionally redundant, but unique in the input. I have no way to  influence the producing system. Further, it is an abstract node-link model. So when I would remove a node/link pair, i have to connect the prevoious link to the next node again in order to keep my model correct.
Merge is not a solution for this problem, I have to do this AFTER import in order to see the pattern.